# Can we call lightbox on Select Onchange javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to call lightbox on Select Onchange javascript?

Comment: Yes it is. Is that all you need to know or are you having particular trouble with something?

Comment: I have particular problem. So please help me to solve it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call a function instead.

onchange="sendForm()">

function sendForm() {
    document.myform.submit()
}